# Twitter Bootstrap: Definir regra CSS específica para tamanhos diferentes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Gostaria de saber como declarar um valor a uma propriedade CSS de acordo com a resolução do navegador no Bootstrap.

Exemplo: Quero que uma borda seja exibida somente em smartphones ou resoluções muito pequenas (col-xs).
O bootstrap prevê uma forma fácil de se fazer isso?

Comment: Você pode [customizar o Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/), por exemplo: [os breakpoints](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints), os [componentes](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#components), etc. Seria isto?

Comment: Se entendi bem você está procurando por Responsive. Dê uma olhada em: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp, que já fala sobre o Boostrap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para isso você vai precisar utilizar a media query do css 3. Vamos pelo seu exemplo:

Todos os elementos que contenham a classe `.borda` devem de ter uma borda de 1px nos dispositivos com tela menor que 768px de largura (celulares), para tanto, no CSS devemos definir as seguintes regras:

```
/* Todos os elementos que contenham a classe 'borda' terão uma borda de 1px preta */
.borda{ border: 1px solid #000; }

/* Agora apenas os dispositivos que tenham resolução menor que 768px terão borda */
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .borda{ border: none; }
}
```

Obs: O exemplo acima foi dado com base neste [link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries)

Comment: @Caputo, removi sua edição pois o comentário estava correto, a media query serve exatamente para que dispositivos com resolução de no mínimo 768px não tenham borda, assim, dispositivos com menos de 768px terão borda.

Comment: Ops, então foi falha de compreensão minha aí. Desculpe e obrigado pelo aviso! Interpretei errado o min-width

Comment: Perfeito, Mateus. Obrigado!